# The complier cannot call 'pivothighs' with argument

Tags: trading, pine-script

I've been trying to make a pivot point high low multitimeframe indicator but still a new learner and have no idea how to fix.

I tried to put 'tf' function in multiple places of code but it's not working.

```
//@version=4

study("Pivot Prices", overlay=true)
tf=input('120')
leftbars = input(10, minval=1, title='Bars to the left')
rightbars = input(2, minval=1, title='Bars to the right')

phigh = pivothigh(high, tf, leftbars,rightbars)
plow = pivotlow(low, tf, leftbars, rightbars)

if phigh
label1 = label.new(bar_index[rightbars], high[rightbars], text=tostring(high[rightbars]), style=label.style_labeldown, color=color.orange)

if plow
label2 = label.new(bar_index[rightbars], low[rightbars], text=tostring(low[rightbars]), s``tyle=label.style_labelup, color=color.green)
```

I want it to be showing multitimeframe perspective but couldn't figure what is wrong in the code.

Comment: It shows 

'Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 7: Cannot call `pivothigh` with arguments (series[float], input string, input integer, input integer); available overloads: pivothigh(series[float], series[float], series[float]) => series[float]; pivothigh(series[float], series[float]) => series[float];'

Comment: 'line 8: Cannot call `pivotlow` with arguments (series[float], input string, input integer, input integer); available overloads: pivotlow(series[float], series[float], series[float]) => series[float]; pivotlow(series[float], series[float]) => series[float];'

'line 10: Undeclared identifier `phigh`;'

'line 13: Undeclared identifier `plow`'

Comment: Please don't add new information as a comment. Instead, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation. `pivothigh()` and `pivotlow()` can take two or three arguments.

```
pivothigh(source, leftbars, rightbars) → series[float]
pivothigh(leftbars, rightbars) → series[float]
```

You are passing four arguments.